# Spring Boot Kafka Consumer Property not applying

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot kafka consumer.
I'm trying to apply this property `spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size=524288000` through application.properties.

Other properties are reflecting but not this property.
Here's the properties used by spring boot

[image]

The property `spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size` in `application.properties` should set `fetch.min.bytes` but it's being set to 1.

Spring Boot Version: 2.7.2
[image]
Kafka Client Version: 2.9.0
[image]

Comment: Please show code as text, not images, but typo? `fetch-min-bytes`, not `size`, otherwise, you can also try `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.[fetch.min.bytes]=X`

Comment: According to Spring Boot Documentation, it is `fetch-min-bytes`. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-min-size

Comment: I also tried `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.fetch.min.bytes` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The square brackets are required if you use properties object. Please add your code as text in your question as a [mcve]